MAUI - MediaPicker PickPhotoAsync always give "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'"
Net 8.0 + MS Toolkit, MVVM, VS 2022, android emulator 11 API 30
I've a listview based on a ObservableCollection of class
public partial class ADVImage : BaseModel //<= extends ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _ADVId;
  
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _description;

    [ObservableProperty]
   private ImageSource _imgData;
}

here I've a command
public partial class ADVModel : BaseModel  //<= extends ObservableObject
{
    public ADVModel()
    {
      Images = new ObservableCollection<ADVImage>();
    }

   [ObservableProperty]
   private string _titolo;

   [ObservableProperty]
   private string _testo;
 
    public ObservableCollection<ADVImage> Images { get; set; }

  [RelayCommand]
  private async void AddImage() //Button in page "Add"
  {
      try
      {
          var result = await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync();
          if (result != null)
          {
              if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                  result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
              {
                  var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, result.FileName);
                  using (var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync())
                  {
                      using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                      {
                          await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream); // <=== HERE
                      }
                      
                      ADVImage aDV = new ADVImage();
                      aDV.ImgData = ImageSource.FromFile(newFile);
                      aDV.Description = "New image";
                      Images.Add(aDV);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          // The user canceled or something went wrong
      }
  }
}

When I reach the point where the stream has to be copied I receive this error:
"System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'"
But why? I've never accessed
In android log I cannot find any error related...
Tryed to download MAUI official samples fron Github and copy-paste code from "PlatformIntegrationDemo".. same issue/same error ...
No solutions working.. chaged Mediapicker with FilePicker (same issue)

why not just use File.Copy?

Have you tried debugging to check where does the object get disposed exactly? Also check if there are any inner exceptions

@Jason no way :(... this is the result
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/GNR5663.JPG'. etc.. in File.Copy

@FreakyAli file are not disposed (by me, mabe internally in ... come place), exception is raised where I wrote "HERE" but before I never read or something on result (only check if it's null and its name). This makes me crazy. But I've seen a  lot of simililar troubles (via Google)

EDIT: Simplified code
var result = await MediaPicker.Default.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions();
if (result != null)
{
ADVImage aDV = new ADVImage();
aDV.ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(result.FullPath);
aDV.Description = "Newi Image";
}
Byte array lenght is correct (>0) but AFTER code IS COMPLETED same error on stream (???)

You need to check why result gives you a disposed stream is what i am trying to tell you here, debug that

@FreakyAli yes but this happens in another thread in a non managed code.. I'll later paste here exception details stack-trace (all this happens OUTSIDE my code..this seems me strage). I've tryied many non-stream ways (ex. File.Copy or commented ALL my code), I'll ever raise this exception,

May be raise a bug with the maui team

Tryed to download MAUI official samples fron Github and copy-paste code from "PlatformIntegrationDemo".. same issue/same error  I did a test by using the official sample PlatformIntegrationDemo you mentioned above on my android emulator 11 (API 30), but I couldn't reproduce this problem. How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?
